# Using Whoosh with a SQLITE3.db (Python)

Tags: python, python-2.7, indexing, sqlite, whoosh

Could someone give me an example of using whoosh for a sqlite3 database, I want to index my database. Just a simple connect and searching through the database would be great. I searched online and was not able to find an examples for sqlite3.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a post-save function `index_data` to your database writers. This post-save should get the data to be written in database, normalize it and index it.

The searcher could be an independent script given an index and queries to be searched for.